# Is comma forbidden in sql select query?

Tags: sql, database, security, select, sql-injection

In our product, we are providing cli option for the customer to fetch necessary details.

We have a script that invokes the java class which executed the query provided and returns the data to the customer. Script name is execute
./execute query  "select name, address from exposedSchema.employee_view"

I want to know from a security perspective if comma(,) is forbidden to be used in the select query?

Should our plan be
Allow:
./execute query  "select * from exposedSchema.employee_view"
Do not allow
./execute query  "select name, address from exposedSchema.employee_view"

Comment: There are numerous places in SQL where a comma is necessary.  There is no security reason to avoid using a comma that I've heard of.

Comment: What are you trying to protect against happening?

Comment: Commas in a `select` are part of the syntax, definitely do not use `select *`!

Answer (score 0):

Actually I would like to advise you use

```
select name, address from exposedSchema.employee_view
```

instead of

```
select * from exposedSchema.employee_view
```

There are considerable number of reasons. Here are some key reasons with a link:

> In SQL Server, and in any common SQL language, the asterisk ( * )
> tells the database engine to return all columns within a table. Using
> “SELECT *” in your queries is a bad idea, and the reasons why we don’t
> recommend this is:
>
> Security – If an unauthorized user gets access to your query and it
> returns * (meaning all columns)  it could leave every column available
> for misuse.
>
> Performance – It should always be faster to return the
> data just the columns you need than for all available columns. When
> using “SELECT *” the column list is resolved each time you run the
> statement, so it is almost always true that it is faster to return
> just the columns you need instead of all columns.
>
> Confusion – As
> things change over time, you really can’t be sure that a query written
> today using “SELECT *” will return results easily digestible by the
> program or report that must consume the data in the future. Columns
> may be added or removed to a table over time, and if you specify
> columns in your SELECT queries you know exactly which ones will be
> returned.

https://seniordba.wordpress.com/2018/06/11/list-table-columns-names-instead-of-using-select/